# Inference of a mixture of logistic regression from simulation data in R

Tags: r, inference, simulation, finite-mixture-model

Here is the setup and the code that allows to simulate the mixture of 15 component of logistic regression; here each component has 5 common variables that it shares with the other component (with different betas though) and 5 specific variables. We have 2500 x 15 observations and we can observe all 80 variables for each observation. The coefficients and the variables are all drawn from i.i.d. standard gaussians.

```r
# some parameters of the simulation
set.seed(42)
n <- 2500  # number of observations by component
k <- 15   # number of components

n_var_com=5
n_var_spec=5

# common explanatory Variables
x_common <- NULL
# specific explanatory Variables
x_specific <- NULL
beta_0 <- NULL
beta_common <- matrix(data = NA, nrow = k, ncol = 5)
beta_specific <- matrix(data = NA, nrow = k, ncol = 5)

for(j in 1:n_var_com){
  x_common <- cbind(x_common, rnorm(n*k))
}
set.seed(42)
# explanatory Variable  specific 
for(j in 1:(n_var_spec * k)){
  x_specific <- cbind(x_specific, rnorm(n*k))
}
for(i in 1:k){
# Parameters of common variables of the logistic regression of each component 
  beta_0[i] <- runif(1, -3, 3)
  for(j in 1:n_var_com){
    beta_common[i,j] <- runif(1, -3, 3)
  }
  # Parameters of specific variables  of the logistic regression for this component
  for(j in 1:n_var_spec) {
    beta_specific[i,j] <- runif(1, -3, 3)
  }
}

x <- cbind(x_common, x_specific)
# Initialization of an empty dataframe to stock data
data <- data.frame()

# Loop on each component to generate data

for (i in 1:k) {
  #  logistic probability for each observation
  index_var_comm = 1:5
  index_var_spec = (1+i*n_var_spec):((i+1)*n_var_spec)
  logit_prob <- beta_0[i] + 
     rowSums(beta_common[i,] * x[(1+(i-1)*n):(i*n), index_var_comm]) + 
     rowSums(beta_specific[i,] * x[(1+(i-1)*n):(i*n), index_var_spec])
    
  # Generating target variable  
  y <- rbinom(n, 1, plogis(logit_prob))
    
  # Combine data of this component with previous simulations
  data_comp <- data.frame(
    x = x[(1+(i-1)*n):(i*n), 1:80],
    y = y,
    plogis(logit_prob),
    matrix(1:5, nrow = n, ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE),
    matrix((1+i*n_var_spec):((i+1)*n_var_spec), nrow = n, ncol = 5, 
            byrow = TRUE),
    component = rep(i, n)  # pour identifier le composant d'origine
  )
  data <- bind_rows(data, data_comp)
}

# check first lines
head(data)
#now shuffling data 

rows <- sample(nrow(data))
data_shuffle<- data[rows, ]
```

Now the problem is the following :

Infer from 'data_shuffle' the original model but with the constraint that we don't know to which component each observation belongs to (the information is kept in data_shuffle for posterior performance evaluation purpose only) nor the number of components.

This means that we need to estimate the number of component, each logistic regression coefs for each component (this is tricky because a selection method of the variables in the logistic regression of the component is needed (only 10 over 80 are contributing!!)) and finally some component classification method of for each observations (a probability vector where each coordinate represents the probability the observation has to belong to the is component).

P.S. : I have tried the flexmix R package without much success to date meaning that even though the algorithm converges, the performance at the confusion matrix level is really poor.